# embedding a font in the code

Tags: theming

I know nothing but the admin functions of Drupal.  The developer of my site used Roboto and other fonts when I asked for Arial.  Now my website design gets completely screwed up in Chrome and Firefox browsers.  The developer has since gone out of business.  I was told that something could be added to the code to "embed' this roboto font so that when someone accesses my site that does not have roboto installed - which is just about everybody apparently - that  roboto will automatically be installed in their computer?  Someone at Go Daddy told me that the problem is that HTTPS should be inserted in the code instead of HTTP.  That the developer does have the roboto code inserted but it should be HTTPS.  I know I probably sound completely stupid but I cannot even find the code to even look at it or CSS style sheets.  I have no idea where the code actually is for my site.  If anyone can assist - I would greatly appreciate it.  My site is nightvisionnv.com.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. HTTPS versus HTTP is a question that is not Drupal related. As for where to look for the code, we cannot tell you, since you didn't say if the fonts were added from a module, or a theme. We cannot list all the possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

As for fixing this - see Shawn Conn's answer.

Some more background:

The "Roboto" font is *already* embedded in your site.  If you look at he markup in your header, it has the following line:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400|Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This should be:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400|Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

to make it work with both HTTP and HTTPS (as already pointed out by Shawn Conn).

Provided this is made to work, it means that if a user don't have Roboto installed, it will be downloaded from the googleapis CDN and cached upon first visit.

The line that inserts that link to the googleapis is *probably* in `html.tpl.php` in your site's theme (but I can't be sure - Drupal allows a site developer to insert such links in the header by other means).

Also, your style sheets uses the following every time a font is mentioned:

```
font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
```

This means: Use "Roboto" when available, otherwise fall back on the browser's default for "sans-serif".  This should work OK in all browsers, including Firefox and Chrome - even if the HTTPS/HTTP mixup mentioned by Shawn Conn stops Roboto from being downloaded.

> Now my website design gets completely screwed up in Chrome and Firefox
>   browsers.

I looked at your website in MSIE, Firefox, and Chrome.  I don't see any obvious problems with it.

Comment: I think the problem OP having is that when the site is in https, browsers simply reject to download the font via http. Changing the "http" to "https" should fix the problem.

Comment: @AyeshK - I think you're right.  +1 for Shawn Conn's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Google Web Fonts will have trouble loading over mixed protocols. Your site forces HTTPS but the URL is set to HTTP. It needs to set to a protocol agnostic URL:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400|Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

In order to find where the problem is trying doing a text search over your code base for "fonts.googleapis.com". It could be inside **html.tpl.php**, **template.php**, or some other location depending on how the dev built the theme.